# Possible to Freeze a Mock of a func?

Tags: unit-testing, autofixture, automoq

I want to test that my `Func` type is actually executed. To do that I have created a `Mock`, but I run into an `Exception` from Autofixture. I tried to `Freeze` just the `Func` (without the `Mock`) and this works. Can someone explain what's happening or guide me to the right way of doing this?

Exception message:

> An exception of type 'Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.IllegalRequestException' occurred in Ploeh.AutoFixture.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Additional information: A request for an IntPtr was detected. This is an unsafe resource that will crash the process if used, so the request is denied. A common source of IntPtr requests are requests for delegates such as Func or Action. If this is the case, the expected workaround is to Customize (Register or Inject) the offending type by specifying a proper creational strategy.

Code:

```
public class DomainClassDummy
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

var frozenFunc = F.Freeze<Func<int, DomainClassDummy>>(); //works
var frozenMockOfFunc = F.Freeze<Mock<Func<int,DomainClassDummy>>>(); //fails
```

Comment: What versions of Moq and AutoFixture are you using? Are you customizing the Fixture or using it as-is?

Comment: I am using Autofixture 3.30.8 and I am cusmizing it: F = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoConfiguredMoqCustomization());

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behavior is due to `AutoConfiguredMoqCustomization`.

When AutoFixture is customized with `AutoConfiguredMoqCustomization`, it relays the creation of the Mock instances to a special builder.
This builder, however, gets the inner type `Func<int,DomainClassDummy>` and creates a mock out of it, passing the two arguments of its constructor: `object`and `IntPtr` and here is where the problem lies.

The default builder for delegates, creates its instances out of a Linq Lambda Expression.

To make it work, you'll have to create the mock yourself and inject it to AutoFixture. Injecting it is the same as freezing, except you specify the instance yourself, instead of telling AutoFixture to create one for you.

Here is what you should do:

```
var mockOfFunc = new Mock<Func<int, DomainClassDummy>>();
F.Inject(mockOfFunc);
```

Answer (score 3):

The explanation given by Marcio Rinaldi is technically correct, but I found the solution unsatisfactory, so I added this ability to [AutoFixture.AutoMoq 3.31.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoFixture.AutoMoq/3.31.1).

This test now passes:

```
[Fact]
public void FixtureCanFreezeUsableMockOfFunc()
{
    // Fixture setup
    var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());
    var expected = fixture.Create<Uri>();
    var mockOfFunc = fixture.Freeze<Mock<Func<Guid, decimal, Uri>>>();
    mockOfFunc
        .Setup(f => f(It.IsAny<Guid>(), 1337m))
        .Returns(expected);

    // Exercise system
    var actual = mockOfFunc.Object(Guid.NewGuid(), 1337m);

    // Verify outcome
    Assert.Equal(expected, actual);
    // Teardown
}
```

Comment: Wow. That is exactly what I am looking for. I will try that out. Thanks.